# Is python statsmodel elastic net regression automatically standard deviation deflated?

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

I cannot find anywhere in internet for this really simple question so I have to ask here.

We know that applying regularization on norm of X you need to consider the standard deviation of your variables and properly normalize them to 1 if you don't want it to affect the penalty you apply to your dataset. I am curious about in statsmodel when I use pyhon elastic net or ridge/lasso, is this automatically handled? Also when I do panel regression with mixed effect model, are the variables also variance deflated properly within each group. E.g. you have a country pnale data with population and GDP growht data. When using statsmodel package, is 1. the GDP and Population are both standardized  before fitting 2. the population/gdp among different country also standardized before fitting?

Comment: Did you check the docs or the source code to see if there is documentation to answer your query?